# How to prove that $\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+\cos^2{t}}\; dt>2\pi$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

Let $$I=\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{1+\cos^2{(t)}}\;dt$$

How to prove, in an elementary way, that $I>2\pi$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a hint:
$$
1+\cos^2(t)\geq 1
$$
for all $t$.

Comment: And another: there exists $t\in [0,2\pi]$ such that $1+\cos^2(t) > 1$ and $1+\cos^2(t)$ is continuous.

Comment: @AlexR Yours is **the** hint.

Comment: @GitGud combined with the one above and elementary properties of the Integral, you have the complete proof for the _strict_ inequality

Comment: Or you can use geometrical approach. Integral is area under graph ...

Comment: @Antoine You still to observe that there's a point such that the graph lies strictly above the $x$-axis.

Comment: @Git Gud Strictly above a line $y=1$ I think. But it was just a hint anyway ...

Answer (score 8):

For a geometric approach, note that the integral $I$ is the arc length of the function $y = \sin x$ on the interval $[0, 2\pi]$. The inequality follows since drawing a straight line from $(0,0)$ to $(2 \pi, 0)$ is strictly shorter than the route the graph of $\sin x$ takes from $(0,0)$ to $(2 \pi, 0)$.

Comment: Excellent.   Then there are lower bounds by drawing  polygons through known points on the curve.